# xctool ...ERROR: build-tests: '' is not a testing target in this scheme

Tags: xcode, swift, xcodebuild, xcode-ui-testing, xctool

i try to run my Xcode UI Tests and just a specific method. It isn't possible with the default **xcodebuild** command line from apple. I found the **xctool** but the tool didn't found my UITestsTarget.

Here my command line:

```
/path/to/xctool -workspace APP.xcworkspace -scheme "APPScheme" test -only UITestsTarget:UITestsClass/UITestsMethod
```

and i got this error: ...ERROR: build-tests: 'UITestsTarget' is not a testing target in this scheme.

with `xcodebuild list` i can see all the informations about project and i see my UITestsTarget.

has someone any ideas?
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xctool doesn`t support Xcode UI testing now. https://github.com/facebook/xctool/issues/534. They told: " At Facebook we are using our own infrastructure (see https://github.com/facebook/webdriveragent) to run E2E tests and as a result we aren't going to work on this feature in the nearest future."