# Is there any kind of order for xcode 8 to execute UI Test cases?

Tags: ios, xcode8, xcode-ui-testing

With xcode 7 there was and alphabetic or numeric order of executing test cases when starts multiple test cases.
E.g.

- test3()
- test9()
- test6()
- test5()
- test7()
- test4()
- test8()

These cases will be executed in order 3-4-5-6-7-8-9

Now with xcode 8 test cases seems to be started in random order.
My question is: Is there a some setting or how to make this to to run test is some order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In XCode 8, what is the way to make test methods run in a particular order within a given XCTestCase class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602686/in-xcode-8-what-is-the-way-to-make-test-methods-run-in-a-particular-order-withi)

Answer (score 1):

1. Tests should be able to work in random order.
2. According [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41614017/751932): test order from command line and from Xcode are different.