# XC UI Testing with AWS device farm giving error "Setup Test skipped: Not enough suites found to execute"?

Tags: swift3, ios10, aws-device-farm, xcuitest, xcode9.2

Archive the project and created the IPA file with development profile after that followed the following link to create the UITest IPA

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-ios-xctest-ui.html

also to reconfirm whether I am doing any wrong checked the following tutorial

https://www.mobdesignapps.fr/blog/2016/9/17/running-your-test-on-aws-device-farm?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=answer&utm_term=37184633

where the steps stated

**Prepare Your iOS XCTest UI Tests**

Before you upload iOS XCTest UI tests to Device Farm for testing, make sure that your iOS XCTest UI test runner bundle is contained within a properly formatted .ipa file. To create an .ipa file, you can place your my-project-nameUITest-Runner.app bundle in an empty Payload directory. Next, archive the Payload directory into a .zip file and then change the file extension to .ipa. The *UITest-Runner.app bundle is produced by Xcode when you build your project for testing, and it can be found in the Products directory for your project.

But whatever I do getting the following error and my test getting skipped
**Setup Test skipped: Not enough suites found to execute**

Didn't understand what I have to do to make it working and can anyone please help to figure out the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you packaging the test for device farm?

Comment: I prepared the package as an enterprise IPA

Comment: Hi @ChowdhuryMdRajibSarwar. Ever succeeded to run Standard env and if yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

Try using Device farm's [custom environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/custom-test-environments.html). The standard environment has a parsing step which can fail. If it does then this error will appear since it can't find the suites.

Comment: custom environment will always work, but not a great idea if you have 50 tests and you want to test only one test case or class. You need to wait for one hour instead of 5 mins.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your UITest target does not have any UITests defined. That's what the `Suites found to execute` message probably means. Does your UITest target define any tests?

Comment: Did you mean that the test method name in XCTest UI class? For example, I have "testPrepareLogin" method. Do I need to mention the name of UI Test target?

Comment: Why not limit the tests in the custom environment using the accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37971495

Answer (score 0):

I've found that it doesn't like Swift tests. Try switching to Obj-C.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine had the same problem, and his solution was to build using Xcode 10 instead of Xcode 11, which seems like an AWS bug to me.